# How to get ringtone list of iPhone programmatically

Tags: iphone, audio, alert

I am developing a iPhone alarm app.
I have to display the list of ringtones.
How can I obtain these names?
And then how use these ringtones for alarm?

Comment: Do you have the ringtones saved some how? Do you want to use the default ringtones?

Comment: I think it's fairly clear that the list of the built-in tones is desired, which I can't find from a Google search.

Answer (score 2):

Apple has set things up so that one cannot use or change the ringtones available programmatically -- see [App Store Guidelines](http://stadium.weblogsinc.com/engadget/files/app-store-guidelines.pdf) . You will need your own files for this.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It's only way for this.Then where can I get these files?

Comment: @HAPPY_TIGER: I do not know if you legally can get the default files. There are many free ringtones available online. Just google around.